# Cookies in template

Tags: cookies

I need to show some part of the page only once, based on cookies. The main problem that I can set cookies only in plugin, hooking init action.

I've read 20 pages of google, this site, asked 2 forums, but I still have this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Chip Bennett is right - you can hook also via init. and can you specify exactly what is the problem of your "logic" ? I have used this method in functions.php more than once . functions.php and plugins are essentially the same, the only difference (as far as you concern) is the loading sequence .

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you can only hook into init via *Plugin*, rather than via the *Theme*?

The [`setup_theme` hook, which fires *when the Theme is setup*, fires *before* the `init` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). Thus, a Theme is perfectly capable of hooking into `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure, that you get the idea.

I need to make some kind of a logic:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])
{
    echo 'Hi, anon!';
    setcookie('mycookie', 1, time()+60*60*24;
}
```

I can't make this functionality using plugins=(

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. Comment on answers or edit details into your original question. You might want to register on site so system recognizes you properly (otherwise you might be treated as different accounts and not have proper access to your question).